# Javascript - rendering input field text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I wrote a function that renders all my selected fields (seats) in a div class.. When I click on them they need to be shown by their name.. 
Now, I want that fields to be written in the input field I selected on click..

```
var rowRange = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
    sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
    map: [
        'aaaaa__aaaaa',
        'aaaaa__aaaaa',
        'aaaaa__aaaaa'
    ],

    naming : {
        top : false,
        getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
            return rowRange[row - 1].toUpperCase() + column;
        },
    },

    click: function () {
        if (this.status() === 'available') {
            $('<li>'+this.settings.label+'</b></li>')
                .appendTo($cart);


            $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);

            return 'selected';
    });
});
```

and this is my form input field

```
 <input type="text" id="selected-seats" class="form-control"  size="20">
```

This example works fine but I have trouble connecting it with input field..

```
if (this.status() == 'available') {
            $('<li>'+this.settings.label+'</b></li>')
                .appendTo($cart);
```

This does not..

```
if (this.status() == 'available') {
            document.getElementById('selected-seats')
                .appendTo($cart);
```

Comment: What about `$('#selected-seats').appendTo($cart)`?

Comment: Also tried. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('selected-seats')
```

The line above returns a pure DOM element, not wrapped by any jQuery object. DOM elements don't have the `appendTo` method - jQuery objects do however. So what you need to do is either to use jQuery to get the element by ID (first example below) or use it to wrap the result of the native `getElementById` method (second example below).

```
// First example
$('#selected-seats').appendTo($cart)

// Second example
var selectedSeatsElement = document.getElementById('selected-seats');
$(selectedSeatsElement).appendTo($cart)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I tried both ways and it doesn't work. I am starting to think it can be related to my input field?

Comment: It might be. Does it find the element when you invoke the `getElementById` method yourself?

Comment: It's not triggering! :/

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Everything is passing without any errors. This part does work             $('<li>'+this.settings.label+'</b></li>'), but when it comes on the example with input field it does nothing..

Comment: Do you get any result when you open the console and type in `document.getElementById('selected-seats')`?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it!

I needed to return value for input field.

```
$('#selected-seats')
                 .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                 .val(this.settings.label)
                 .appendTo($cart);
```